# Mongoose.find() parametrized doesn't find anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this simple function that execute two queries to `mongoDB` from `Node`

```
function getEstablecimientosParadas(req,res){
      let tipo=req.body.tipoParada;
      let id_esta=req.body.id_esta;

      let paradas ={
        paradasMetro:[],
        paradasCercanias:[],
        paradasBus:[]
      }

        console.log("id_esta_param:"+id_esta);
        var find1= EstablecimientosMetro.find();
        var find2= EstablecimientosCercanias.find({"id_establecimiento":id_esta});
        var find3= EstablecimientosBus.find({"id_establecimiento":id_esta});

        find1.exec((err,paradasM) => {
          if(err){
            console.log('Error en la peticion(Paradas metro)');
          }else{
            if(!paradasM){
              console.log('No hay paradas de metro');
            }else{
              paradas.paradasMetro=paradasM;
              console.log(paradasM);
            }
          }
        });

        find2.exec((err,paradasC) => {
          if(err){
            console.log('Error en la peticion(Paradas cercanias)');
          }else{
            if(!paradasC){
              console.log('No hay paradas de cercanias');
            }else{
              paradas.paradasCercanias=paradasC;
              console.log(paradasC);
            }
          }
        });

        find3.exec((err,paradasB) => {
          if(err){
            console.log('Error en la peticion(Paradas bus)');
          }else{
            if(!paradasB){
              console.log('No hay paradas de bus');
            }else{
              paradas.paradasBus=paradasB;
              console.log(paradasB);
            }
          }
        });

        Promise.all([
          find1,
          find2,
          find3
        ]).then((value) => {
          res.status(200).send({
            paradasResponse:paradas,
          });
        });

    }
```

This is what `console.log()` show me:

```
id_esta_param:59b2a7c4fcaf252adc4416d4
59b2a7c4fcaf252adc4416d4
[ { _id: 59c9416bde59b020c0403b58,
    id_parada: 598c9be810ebd9a7a94433f5,
    id_establecimiento: 59b2a7c4fcaf252adc4416d4,
    id_seccion: 597f96f82769efbe7301f97b,
    orden: 4 },
  { _id: 59c9416bde59b020c0403b59,
    id_parada: 598c9be810ebd9a7a94433f7,
    id_establecimiento: 59b2a7c4fcaf252adc4416d4,
    id_seccion: 597f96f82769efbe7301f97b,
    orden: 4 } ]
[]
[]
```

Mi problem is that I dont understand why the `.find({"id_establecimiento":id_esta)` doesn't find anything on their collections, but when I do the `.find()` without params it find evertything and as you can see the `id_establecimiento` params is the same on the request param and in the id_establecimiento field in the collection.

PD: There two documents on the other two collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create `ObjectID` from your string param `id_esta`. For example:

```
import {ObjectID} from 'mongodb';

// ...

const objID = ObjectID(id_esta)
```

and use it in your query, like this:

```
const query = EstablecimientosCercanias.find({'id_establecimiento': objID});
```

Comment: Its a query for node, its look like an angularjs import, evens o, its doesnt work either requiring the ObjectId

Comment: `import` is a feature of ECMAScript6, not AngularJS. You can simply rewrite import with `const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID`.

Comment: It´s true, but im not using `mongodb` package, Im using `mongoose`

Comment: Also, with mongoose you can use next example: `const objId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(id_esta)`. @Hictus

Comment: The problem was that I was saving the object not as an ObjectId only as string, it means that searching for only string should work, but I dont know why it doesnt... saving the field as ObjectId and searching for it as ObjectId works! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

Var Id = new ObjectId(id_esta)

   EstablecimientosCercanias.find({"id_establecimiento":id})
.sort({id_esta_param:-1})
.populate()
.exec(function(err,ata){
    //do your code
    })
```

Comment: I have to add some `.sort()` and `.populate()` before so I use the `.exec()` function. but I removed it on the question.

Comment: Updated my code to show populate and sort check that @hictus

Comment: Try  the updated code because if finding an id then it should of objectid type as mongodb stores it in objectid type@hictus

Comment: I tried and it show me `TypeError: ObjectId is not a constructor`

Comment: ObjectId must be defined check my second line in code

Comment: I had `var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId();` but I also tried to split it in two lines as your example and it doesnt work either

Comment: The version Im using is 4.9.6

Comment: The problem was that I was saving the object not as an ObjectId only as string, it means that searching for only string should work, but I dont know why it doesnt... saving the filed as ObjectId and searching for it as ObjectId works! Thank you very much for your help!